# Scrapy: where to put spider initialization code

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

What is the best practice for this?

Say, I want to initialize some counters or read a file to use it later in parsing. How would I do that? Override `__init__`? Or there are some other better ways?..

Answer (score 0):

depends on your need , what ever it is project level , or simply spider level override **init** is the best approach.